# Marging two cell in one column in fpdf

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, fpdf

**I am fetching data form database and showing it in pdf file using fpdf, I am trying to arrange two cell in one column.But it is not coming properly. what is wrong in my code .**

''''

```
$pdf->Cell(18,5,$data['category'],'LR',0);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,5,utf8_decode($data['subcategory'] . chr(10) . 
$data['entertainment_unit']),'1',1);
$pdf->MultiCell(32,5,utf8_decode($data['warea'] . chr(10) . $data['earea']),'1',1);
$pdf->Cell(18,5,$data['wdesign'],'LR',1);
```

'''

[Output coming like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ncQW.png)

[I want output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8eww.png)

Answer (score 0):

See comment below

```
$pdf->MultiCell(
 30, 
 5,
 utf8_decode($data['subcategory'] . chr(10) . $data['entertainment_unit']),
'1', <--shouldn't this be an integer?
 1
 );
```

Edit: Looks like you have a few integers that are listed as strings. Try changing them to an integer and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Any other solution for  this

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the documentation here- http://www.fpdf.org/